# Angular 8 rxjs long subscription process

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to sent to a update request with Rxjs in angular 8. So everything goes good. But Rxjs subscription takes long time. So error messages is showing on the screen with too late.

What should I do resolve this issue?

Here is my subscription implementation.

```
    const  updateSubscrition = this.service.updateUserProfile(this.userToUpdate)
        .pipe(
            tap(res => {
                if (res) {
                    this.layoutUtilsService.showActionNotification(_saveMessage, _messageType, 2000, true, true);
                }
            }),
            takeUntil(this._onDestroy),
            finalize(() => {
                this.disableFields = false;
                this.loading = false;
            })
        )
        .subscribe(
            res => res,
            error => this.errorMessage = error
        );
```

I appreciate any helps.

Thanks

Comment: At first glance - everything is okayish. Take a look on the network tab and request time

Comment: So there is no problem with respond and request actually. I tested api with Postman so request happen too fast.

Comment: This code is fine but such as I don't know where it exists, what are errors and what are other parts: console.log(Date.now()) at the start and on subscribe, debug with time, look on other parts. A simple subscription couldn't be slow. Maybe you use delay somewhere + check network tab to be sure(postman is fine, but look in browser)